# Intuitive way to understand "Run-Length Encoding"

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, runtime-analysis, data-compression, signal-processing

Run-Length Encoding is the simple form of lossless data compression in which compression in which *runs* (execution) of data are stored as a single data value and count rather than as the original *run* (execution).

Now the definition is there but what's an intuitive way of thinking about this?

Comment: What does "(execution)" mean in your question?  The "runs" in run-length encoding are sub-sequences of a larger sequence in which all of the data have the same value.  For example, in the string "abcccccde", the "ccccc" is a _run_ of five 'c's.  One simplistic run-length encoded version of the string might be "ab5cde".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Run" doesn't mean "execution". It means "sequence of identical things", as in "the football team had a run of wins."

So the intuition is simply that it's more efficient to say "ten $a$'s" than "$aaaaaaaaaa$".